# Bootstrap- JQuery library files not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying style the select tag using bootstrap. The problem is coming from the JQuery library file. The PHP code doesn't work because of the JQUery file. And if I remove the Jquery file, the PHP code functions properly but the selectpicker class doesn't work in the select tag.

```
            <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

         <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- JQuery library -->
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



    <!--- Select libraries --->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.9.3/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.9.3/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>




            <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo SITEURL; ?>/lib/js/jscal2/src/js/jscal2.js"></script>
            <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo SITEURL; ?>/lib/js/jscal2/src/js/lang/en.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo SITEURL; ?>/lib/js/jscal2/src/css/jscal2.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo SITEURL; ?>/lib/js/jscal2/src/css/border-radius.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo SITEURL; ?>/lib/js/jscal2/src/css/gold/gold.css" />


            </head>






 <-------SELECT CODE----->

<select class="selectpicker" name="partyCode" id="partyCode" data-width="530px"> 
                    <?php //echo getAgentASMOption($partyCode);
                     echo getAgentASMOption($_SESSION['party_Code']);
                 //   echo '<br/>' .$mort01. '<br/>';
                    ?>
                    </select>
```

Comment: The last time I checked the class for select elements in Bootstrap was called "form-control".

Comment: @DevNiels It still is :) And why is it jQuery which isn't working? Do you have a proof for that? I think you should try using the class `form-control` instead of `selectpicker` for you `select`.

Comment: So I used form-control instead of selectpicker. That is working. How do I change it's width? And the JQuery library is still causing the PHP code not to work. So I removed it.

Comment: it should be safe to use both classes form-control and selectpicker if your selectpicker class contains some styling that you need